# Why is this PHP code running on my local server and not on my live server (Local PHP is 7.2 - Live is 5.4)

Tags: php, wordpress

This code works perfectly on my local server, but doesn't show a thing on the live server.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
  $args = array('hide_empty=0');

  $terms = get_terms('startup-category', $args);
  if ( ! empty($terms) && ! is_wp_error($terms) ) {
      $count = count($terms);
      $i = 0;
      $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive"> <button class="cta fil-cat" href="" data-rel="all">All</button>';
      foreach ($terms as $term) {
          $i++;
          $term_list .= ' <button class="cta fil-cat" data-rel="' . preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</button> ';
          if ($count != $i) {
              $term_list .= '';
          }
          else {
              $term_list .= '</p>';
          }
      }
      echo $term_list;
  }
  ?>
```

After some digging, I removed the if statement and the PHP spit out the html contained here:

```
$term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive"> <button class="cta fil-cat" href="" data-rel="all">All</button>';
```

The rest of the code does nothing.

Comment: What does your PHP error log say? And you're crazy if you expect anything to run on PHP 4.4 anymore. Especially since WP has only supported PHP5 for many years now.

Comment: Sorry, typed this out too quick, meant to put 5.4.

Comment: Have you checked your WordPress version too? Are they the same between dev and prod environment?

Comment: Yep, first thing I checked.

Comment: Afraid to confirm that this snippet runs properly on both PHP 7.2 and 5.4. It's most probably something wrong with `get_terms()` where the if statement returned false on your live server. You'll have to find that out by checking if `$terms` is empty or it returned WP_Error or not.

Answer (score 0):

Set your Live PHP version to 7.2!
This should be the very obious solution...
But if the problem still continue, try adding debug messages on your PHP code to track down where the issue came from.